# How get last inserted id in sqlite xamarin forms

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

I want to get last inserted id of my query this

```
public IEnumerable<DraftOrderInfoTable> SaveDraftOrderInfo(int orderno, int customerid, string customername, string customeremail, string orderdate)
    {
        var draftorderinfo = new DraftOrderInfoTable
        {
            OrderNo = orderno,
            CustomerId = customerid,
            CustomerName = customername,
            CustomerEmail = customeremail,
            OrderDate = orderdate,
        };

        _connection.Insert(draftorderinfo);
    }
```

Please tell me how to get last inserted id ??

Answer (score 0):

After insert query, just use the SQLite last_insert_rowid() function to get the value of the SQLite autoincrement field that was just generated:

```
select last_insert_rowid();
```